# Print contact details to PDF

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I need to get some contact detail and print it to PDF. Is there any way to do this in Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you create a PDF in your application, it will not be accessible by other apps or your computer. The solution is emailing that file. Thus, you should send the details to a server and get it converted to a PDF then download it on the phone or, the server may email it for you.
There are many web services which will do this for you. See this: http://blog.nitropdf.com/2008/01/free-online-web-services-to-create-view-share-and-edit-pdf-files/

Comment: I don't mind if the pdf is not accessible to others applications. Is there a way to create pdf files in wp 7 application?

Answer (score 0):

There's a branch of the SharpPDF project called [PdfSharp for WP7](http://pdfsharpwp7.codeplex.com/).  It states that it is not fully featured.  It may/may not provide you with enough functionality for what you need.  I haven't personally looked at the library, so you may wish to download it and see what features it provides.

Other than that, one of the most common ways to generate a PDF document using C# is iTextSharp.  This most likely uses advanced features in the .NET framework and probably won't recompile for the Windows Phone.  You could code up your own converter service that could also dispatch the newly created PDF via email once done.  The app would usually be hosted somewhere (on a server or in the cloud) and would be accessible via WCF.